74HC04 Input Issue
In a packaging machine, the machine starts working every time a button is pressed. R2 is a pull-up resistor. Button information goes to the machine from this pin. 5 V and GND come from the machine. I measure the tip of R2 connected to the 5 V line around 3.5 V. When I press the button, this tip becomes 0 V. After a while, U5's A pin constantly pulls itself to 1 V and the Y pin becomes active, the LED lights up continuously and the machine starts working continuously. The interesting thing is that I give 2.5 V directly to this pin and the LED goes off, then lights up again when I let it go. When I give 5 V momentarily, it recovers and continues to work as before. I reduce the supply voltage of U6 and U5 to 2.5 V because in some machines I read 2.4 V from the tip of this pull-up resistor. This causes the LED to work unstable.

Why do I read low voltages like 3.5 V from the pull-up resistor instead of 5V?
Why does it pull the U5 input to 1 V after a certain period of time?
Why does it fix itself when you apply 5 V to the U5 input momentarily?



If I remove the R2 resistor, the line floats and the machine works continuously.
If I remove the button, nothing changes. If 74HC04 is in error, it remains like that.
Measure the R2 resistor from GND and U5's A pin


Does anyone have an idea? It's a very annoying problem.
Update:
I wrote HC in the title because I thought the HC model was common. There is a 74LVC1G04DBVR in the system. I thought the difference between HC and LCV was power consumption, but I learned that they are also slightly different. (ESD diode, CMOS etc.)
In the tests I did today, even though I removed the LDO and supply the 74LVC04 with 5 V, the problem is the same. It pulls the input to 0.5 V levels. Once I manually give 5 V to the A pin, the problem is solved.


Are you measuring voltage on both sides of R2? If so, then you're measuring the voltage drop of the resistor rather than measuring the potential between 5V and ground.

I am measuring the resistance with GND. Actually I am measuring the pull-up path. Logically it should be 5V when the button is not pressed and 0V when it is pressed. This is not the voltage drop of the resistor.

First of all: Please [edit] your question to add new information and clarifications. Comments are not this this. -- This was not the point Colin asked. What voltage do you measure at the 5V side of R2 in each of the described situations? -- What happens if you disconnect the button/pedal? (You need to find out, which part causes the voltage drop.)

Are those measurements done with something connected on button connector or without? Is the chip really LVC1G04 or something else?

A circuit with the HC04 would indeed show these symptoms. Please ensure that the schematic does not contain errors.

Very likely you have a noise or ground  issue which might trigger a latch-up. Is the button on the same board with U5 or connected with long wires to the board? I would guess LDO oscillating as I see you have the minimum capacitor value specified in the datasheet but you said you tried with 5v without LDO and had the same results.

What happens if you disconnect the machine petal button and temporarily interface a small pushbutton to emulate the press? Then does the LED operate correctly? If so, then it sounds like either the petal button is not a simple “short to ground” type or the circuit within the machine which interfaces and reads the petal input is in conflict with your own circuit’s pullup network. Does the machine have a schematic you can look at instead of trying to work off of measured external voltages?

To further expand on CL's comment.  The 74HC1G04 and 74LVC1G04 will work very differently in this situation.  You say HC in your description, but your schematic shows LVC.  Please clarify this.


Why do I read low voltages like 3.5 V from the pull-up resistor instead of 5V?

You're pushing the input of the inverter above the supply voltage of 2.5V. So there's a current flowing from R2 into the inverter's VCC pin via the input protection diode internal to the inverter. There's little enough load on the 2.5V line that this input current pushes the VCC line up above 2.5V. This current then flows from VCC to the inverter output and into the input protection diode of whatever MCU is connected to the output of that inverter. After all, presumably, the reason for the 2.5V power to the inverter is that there's a similarly low-voltage digital input attached to it. Otherwise the 2.5V would be useless and the thing could run from 5V using a 74HC14.

A HC04 or LVC04 is not the right chip to use. It should be an inverter with a Schmitt-trigger input, say HC14 or LVC14.
Furthermore, exposing the input of a little CMOS inverter to an external connector with a cable going to a pedal is foolish. That inverter can be easily wiped out by static electricity.
There are many ways to make a more reliable circuit, so here's but one. C1 gets charged when pedal is depressed, and discharged when the pedal is released. The charge and discharge rate are similar. It takes about 50ms of pedal depression for the capacitor voltage to cross the upper threshold of the Schmitt trigger inverter. This circuit also debounces the pedal, and provides a degree of isolation between the pedal and the CMOS inverters.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The LVC series has no input protection diode to VCC, making it 5V tolerant on the inputs (one of its selling features).  The question title and text states HC series, but the schematic in the question shows an LVC part.  The questioner needs to clarify this.  Regardless, I like your circuit.
